# sending hex data over serial port with checksum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to write a code to send hex serial data to a radio and receive hex data in response. radio_init_buf variable store the hex data to be sent. The last two bytes with store checksum. radio_init_buf[3] tells the size.

```
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
import serial

class serial_communication():
  PORT = 'COM2'
  # RETURN_VALUE = None

def list_serial_ports(self):
    """ Lists serial port names

        :raises EnvironmentError:
            On unsupported or unknown platforms
        :returns:
            A list of the serial ports available on the system
    """
     if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(0,10)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result

def serial_open(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial()
    self.ser.baudrate = 9600
    self.ser.port = sc.PORT
    self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    self.ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
    self.ser.writeTimeout = 1000
    self.ser.timeout = 1000
    try:
        self.ser.open()
        print("Port OPENED")
        self.initialize(self.ser)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error opening serial port: " + str(e))
        exit()
    return self.ser

def checksum(self, crc_packet, crc_packet_length):
    crc_table= np.array([0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
    0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
    0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
    0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
    0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
    0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
    0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
    0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
    0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
    0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
    0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
    0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
    0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
    0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
    0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
    0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
    0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
    0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
    0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
    0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
    0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
    0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
    0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
    0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
    0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
    0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
    0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
    0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
    0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040],dtype=np.uint16)
    saved_crc_byte1 = crc_packet[crc_packet_length - 1]
    saved_crc_byte2 = crc_packet[crc_packet_length - 2]
    crc_packet[crc_packet_length - 1] = 0
    crc_packet[crc_packet_length - 2] = 0
    crc = 0
    for crc_loop in range(0,crc_packet_length):
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc_table[(crc ^ crc_packet[crc_loop]) & 0xFF]


def initialize(self,serial_port):
    ser = serial_port
    if ser.isOpen():
        print("Initialising...")
        try:
            ser.flushInput()  # flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
            ser.flushOutput()  # flush output buffer, aborting current output
            # and discard all that is in buffer
            # write data
            #f = open('F:/output.txt', 'wb')
            radio_init_buf = np.array([0xAA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x09, 0x32, 0x0, 0x0],dtype=np.uint8)
            #radio_init_buf="\xAA\x00\x00\x08\x09\x32\x00\x00"
            print(radio_init_buf)
            self.checksum(radio_init_buf,radio_init_buf[3])
            print(radio_init_buf)
            ser.write(radio_init_buf)

            serial.time.sleep(0.5)  # give the serial port sometime to receive the data
            #return_value = ser.read(7)
            print(return_value)

            print("Initialisation Complete")
            #comm Link Check
            print("Communication Link Checking..")
            comm_check_buf = np.array([0xAA, 0x06, 00, 6, 0x0B, 0x70],dtype=np.uint8)
            ser.write(comm_check_buf)
            print("Link Check Complete")

            #clear non-volatile memory
            clear_nvm_buf = np.array([0xAA, 0x82, 00, 7, 1, 0, 0],dtype=np.uint8)
            self.checksum(clear_nvm_buf, clear_nvm_buf[3])
            ser.write(clear_nvm_buf)


            #ser.close()

        except Exception as e1:
            print ("error communicating...: " + str(e1))
            ser.close()

    else:
        print("cannot open serial port ")

sc = serial_communication()
print(sc.list_serial_ports())
sc.serial_open()
```

When i run the code i get:

```
['COM1', 'COM2', 'COM3']
Port OPENED
Initialising...
[170   0   0   8   9  50   0   0] 
[170   0   0   8   9  50   0   0]
b'\xaa\x90\x00\x12\x01\x0c\x00'
Initialisation Complete
Communication Link Checking..
Link Check Complete
```

Instead of [170 0 0 8 9 50 0 0], i want the hex data.

Also, it is not returning radio_init_buf with checksum. The result after calling checksum is same.

Comment: After the loop in checksum() you don't write the "crc" back into "crc_packet".

Answer (score 1):

Displaying in hex:

```
for n in radio_init_buf:
    print("{:#x}".format(n), end='')
print()
```

{:#x} - a format string, #: adds the 0x prefix, x: presentation will be in hex,
In one line:

```
print(("{:#x} "*len(radio_init_buf)).format(*radio_init_buf))
```

It creates a string of length len(radio_init_buf). 
In *radio_init_buf , '*' unpacks the list.